# How do I get array _ids of documents failed to insert/delete/update in bulk operation?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

In case of [bulkWrite()](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#bulkWrite-java.util.List-com.mongodb.client.model.BulkWriteOptions-), I want array of _ids of successfully processed documents OR failed documents, along with reason for failure.

Following is the attempt I made. Suggest more easy approach if possible.

```
try {
    collection.insertMany(documents, new InsertManyOptions().ordered(false));
} catch (DuplicateKeyException dke) {
    LOGGER.error("{}", dke);
} catch (MongoBulkWriteException mbwe) {
    List<BulkWriteError> errors = mbwe.getWriteErrors();
    for (BulkWriteError error : errors) {
        LOGGER.error("{}", error.getMessage());
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    LOGGER.error("{}", ex.getCause());
}
```

When I insert document with duplicate _ids, I supposed to get [DuplicateKeyException](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#insertMany-java.util.List-com.mongodb.client.model.InsertManyOptions-) as per javadoc, but I am getting MongoBulkWriteException.

I am using java 8 and mongodb 3.2.1 drivers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

insertMany throws only the following exceptions:

> - MongoBulkWriteException - if there's an exception in the bulk write operation
> - MongoException - if the write failed due some other failure

However the exception carries the cause of it and in the case of a duplicated id will be something like:

```
insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: test.restaurants.$_id_  dup key: { : ObjectId('56c8ac3146235e4898bb696c') }
```

So since you have the information in the message you can extract with a regular expression the ids of the documents that failed in an array.

The code would be something like that (I am giving it inline in your code):

```
        List<String>duplicateIds = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<BulkWriteError> errors = mbwe.getWriteErrors();
        for (BulkWriteError error : errors) {

            LOGGER.error("{}", error.getMessage());

            // extract from error.message the id of the duplicated document, (11000 is the duplicate id code)
            if (error.getCode() == 11000) {
                Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[0-9a-f]{24}")
                        .matcher(error.getMessage());
                m.find();
                duplicateIds.add(m.group());
            }

        }
        // here the duplicateIds will hold all the found ids, you can print them in console for example:
        System.out.println(duplicateIds.toString());
        // and do whatever else you like with them
```

The above code will catch the duplicated Ids - if you want to make it to catch other errors it is easy to adapt it accordingly.

**UPDATE**:

If you want to use `bulkWrite()` you can use exactly the same code since it throws the same exceptions `(MongoBulkWrite, MongoException)` as `insertMany()`, see [BulkWrite()](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#bulkWrite-java.util.List-com.mongodb.client.model.BulkWriteOptions-)

If you want to update the code to catch other exceptions it is easily expandable:

1. see what the specific message and error code is for the exception you want to catch from the logs.
2. add an if block as the one I gave for that particular error code to extract the ids with a regular expression and add them to the array you have initialized for that kind of error
3. do your handling in the end

Comment: Thanks loannis, your answer is what I am using now. I can catch DuplicateKeyErrors this way, but what about other errors? Also I mentioned bulkUpdate, bulkDelete operations, how do I catch errors in those?

Comment: I don't think it is valid as mongodb just throws the first duplicate index it encountered even if there were many duplicates